# Jenkinsfile exit a parallel stage when parameter is empty

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the belo Jenkinsfile where I take user input for one and/or two parallel steps/stages. If the user input is empty, how can I exit that step/stage?
For example, if the user didn't enter any value for `firstTask_build_number` I need to `echo "firstTask_build_number is empty - aborting firstTask!"` and exit that. How can I exit safely?

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        string(name: 'firstTask_build_number', defaultValue: '', description: 'Build ID of firstTask')
        string(name: 'secondTask_build_number', defaultValue: '', description: 'Build ID of secondTask')

    }

    stage("Parallel") {
    steps {
        parallel (
            "firstTask" : {
                if (firstTask_build_number.size() == 0) {
                   echo "firstTask_build_number is empty - aborting firstTask!"
                }
                else {  
                   //do some stuff
                }
            },
            "secondTask" : {
                if (secondTask_build_number.size() == 0) {
                   echo "secondTask_build_number is empty - aborting secondTask!"
                }
                else {  
                   //do some stuff
                }
            }
        )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is that valid syntax within the `parallel` for declarative? It looks like it would error.

Answer (score 0):

You can just `return` out of it.

```
parallel (
    "firstTask" : {
        if (firstTask_build_number.size() == 0) {
           echo "firstTask_build_number is empty - aborting firstTask!"
           return
        }
        else {  
           //do some stuff
        }
    }
)
```